# Process of getting a token on an exchange?

Tags: tokens, exchanges, erc-20

Does anyone know what the typical process of getting a token on exchanges is?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would have to be worth the effort on the part of the exchange before they would list it. (Depending on the exchange, I suppose.)

If your token isn't widely used, then the exchange isn't going to make any money from listing/trading it. There is presumably a point where the value they could make outweighs the cost of the process of adding it, at which point you might have more luck.